# Compare two columns row by row without using for loop

Tags: r

My data:

```
x1    x2      result
abc   abc      1
abc   def      0
def   def      1
```

Two columns when compared give a result of 1 and 0, if matched 1 else 0.
I know I can do it with for loop but is there a function for it?

I tried using *compare* but I think it no longer exists.

---

**Edit:** Searched online for compare package and tried to use the compare function but it didn't work.

Comment: `as.integer(df$x1 == df$x2)`. BTW, why a 0 in the 3rd row?

Comment: You need to be way more specific. You tried `compare` from what package? What code have you written so far?

Comment: If those columns are of class `factor` you will need to compare them with `as.integer(as.character(df$x1) == as.character(df$x2))`.

Comment: oh soory 1 in 3rd

Comment: So if i compare them using as.integer even though they are string it shold work?

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
df$result <- ifelse(df$x1 == df$x2, 1, 0)
```

This reads if the two columns x1 and x2 are equal, then result is 1, and if they are not equal, result is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(result=ifelse(x1==x2,1,0))
```

similar to the former answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `==` and implicit conversion (boolean --> numeric):

```
df$result <- (df$x1==df$x2)*1
# or skip the parentheses and *1 if TRUE/FALSE values are OK
```

Comment: `do.call("==",dat[-3])*1`